# html disabled button, display error on click

Tags: html, button

If I set button to disabled, and someone clicks it, how can I make it display another div, which contains explanation why its disabled?

I have no clue how to do this, and would realy appreciate some help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this a while ago. I think the solution was to wrap a div around the button and detect a click on the div, via jquery. Not pretty but gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it using javascript onClick event.

There are many ways to do that. You can create an element using `document.createElement` and a text node using `document.createTextNode` to create your own message panel.

or you can just create a div then target it using querySelectors of javascript then use `innerHTML`.

I wrote some codes here for you. pls check the link:
https://jsfiddle.net/jLt5hjn8/

Comment: That button is not disabled.